# Firebase Admin: Retrieve phoneNumber from Uid

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using phoneAuth for app authentication and store the Firebase Uids in a custom backend. Is there a method to retrieve the phone number from a uid? I only found methods to get user by uid OR user by phone number.

```
Task<UserRecord> task = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid)
.addOnSuccessListener(userRecord -> {
  // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
  System.out.println("Successfully fetched user data: " + userRecord.getUid());
})
.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
  System.err.println("Error fetching user data: " + e.getMessage());
});
```

The userRecord doesn't contain the phone number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Firebase 5.3.0
`userRecord.getPhoneNumber()` works also for userRecords returned for `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid)`.